# What is "wrong" with my ArrayList?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I guess I'm confused on how the Array list works or maybe more than likely its my code???

For my application, I am entering a numeric value into a numeric up/down control, then clicking a button.  The button adds the value to an ArrayList.  I then click a different button to display all of the values in the ArrayList to a rich text box control.  The values are duplicates though.  Looks something like this in the rich text box

> 100
>   200
>   200
>   300
>   300
>   300
>   425
>   425
>   425
>   425

Where am I steering wrong?

```
lftMtrAccelRates.Add(LftMtr_Accel_Incr.Value)
        lftMtrAccelRates.TrimToSize()

Private Sub btnPrintArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintArray.Click
    Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lftMtrAccelRates.ToArray())
    rchTxtBox.Text = message
End Sub
```

Comment: show the code to fill `arraylist`

Comment: The code you posted works as it should. Do you know how to use the debugger? Set a breakpoint on the `lftMtrAccelRates.Add(LftMtr_Accel_Incr.Value)` part so that you can check if the problem is occurring when you add to the array list or when you dump the results to the rich textbox.

Comment: I figured it out....well sort of.  Originally I had the commented out lines of code (see code snapshot) inside the For Next loop.  I took those lines out of the loop and now the ArrayList is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim rowNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim rowNumber2 As Integer = 1
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow Then Continue For
        row.HeaderCell.Value = "Step " & rowNumber
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentCell = LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount - 1).Cells(0)
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = LftMtr_Accel_Incr.Value
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = LftMtr_Decel_Incr.Value
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = LftMtr_Speed_Incr.Value
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = test_Time_Incr1.Value

        Me.LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Me.LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Me.LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Me.LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
        'lftMtrAccelRates.Add(LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)
        'lftMtrAccelRates.Add(LftMtr_Accel_Incr.Value)
        'lftMtrAccelRates.TrimToSize()
        'txtboxArrayVal1.Text = lftMtrAccelRates.Capacity
    Next
```